# User session helper class

Tags: php, object-oriented, session

I write this session helper class to use it inside my projects for managing the `$_SESSION` variables setup after an user login or logout. It's very simple and after some tests it seems to work smoothly and fine.

The class doesn't have a constructor, this because the needed parameters that are the username and the user id are passed directly to the `setSession` method.

The `sessionCode` method is instead only a code who is used to check if the user is logged in or not, this to limit the access to certain pages if needed.

```
<?php
namespace library;

class SessionHelper{

private $username;
private $id;
private $ip;

public function setSession(string $email,int $id){
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['session_code'] = $this->sessionCode();
    $_SESSION['user_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $email;

    return true;
}

public function sessionStatus(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['session_code'])){
        if(hash_equals($_SESSION['session_code'], $this->sessionCode())){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }    
}

public function unsetSession(){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    return true;
}

private function sessionCode(){
    return hash('sha256', session_id());
}

}

?>
```

USAGE EXAMPLE AFTER A LOGIN SCRIPT:

```
<?php
require_once 'SessionHelper.php';

use library\SessionHelper as SessionHelper;

$session = new SessionHelper;

$session->setSession('user1', '4');

?>
```

USAGE ON RESTRICTED ACCESS PAGES

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'library/Autoloader.php';

use library\SessionHelper as SessionHelper;

$session = new SessionHelper;

if($session->sessionStatus() != true){
  header('Location: index');
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the point of `session_regenerate_id()` here? I also can't see how you're using the session code in a safe manner. You must be accessing `$_SESSION` outside this helper class, which defeats the point of having this class. The idea behind classes is that they abstract things for you. So it shouldn't matter whether you use `$_SESSION` to implement this class, or something else, you can always use it in the same way.

Comment: the regenerate id is used to regenerate the session id after a successful login. Do you have suggestion about session code?

Comment: I know what `session_regenerate_id()` does, and when you use it, but why do you need to regenerate the session id after a successful login? I don't see the point of that. No, I don't have a suggestion about the session code, but I would like to see how it's being used by you.

Comment: I've used it because some developers here in past have suggested me to regenerate te session id after an user login. The use of the session code will be `if(!isset($_SESSION['session_code']))` ..so it will be only a check. I'm thinking to implement this control inside a class method

Comment: Yes, I also think it should be a method inside the helper class. Given the way you use the session code it could be a simple boolean, or even a single value like 1, instead of a 8 character pseudo-random string. You're only checking its presence, not the fact that it's a complex code. A better key would then be: `user_logged_in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a SessionHelper but a UserSessionHelper in the first place. A session is a container that could contain anything, not only user credentials. A shopping cart items for example. Therefore you have to either extend its functionality or at least rename a class.

In 2018 you are obligatory supposed to utilize [a PSR-4: Autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) so not to include your class definitions manually.

What is most important, I don't see any *getSession()* method. Are you checking $_SESSION array directly? If so, that makes you class essentially incomplete. When writing OOP, you must encapsulate the full functionality, leaving something outside just makes no sense.

Given there is no constructor, consider using static methods, it will save you the very absent constructor call.

Comment: ok, so how do you will implement the getSession() method?

Comment: You have working code, so you will already have implemented something similar to the proposed getSession() method. All you have to do is to bring it within the confines of your helper class.